# How to connect a ReactJS Form to a Django model to automatically obtain fields (foreignkeys, choices etc.)

Tags: django, reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a quite complex Django model that is connected to my ReactJS frontend through a DRF API. Inside this model, many instances are ForeignKey or CharFields that include an array of options to be selected. 
Can you please tell me if there's a way I can have my React form to inherit the information of all the fields, instead of writing out the form manually?
I'd need the frontend form in React to "read" through the right API call and get all the fields from there. 
How can I achieve this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what have you tried ? share some input and output

Comment: Hi! At this moment my form is fully written out, field by field. Since I have no idea where to start with getting fields "automatically" from DRF, there's not much I can share here in terms of output.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using RetrieveUpdateAPIView from DRF

```
class GetDateAndUpdate(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    queryset = YOURMODEL.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YOURMODELSerializer        
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,IsOwner]

# in urls.py 
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/update/$',
                GetDateAndUpdate.as_view(),
                name='update',
                ),
```

you can find more here 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview

Comment: Hi! Thank you. I am aware of this APIView and in fact I have implemented it. The missing puzzle piece is on the React side. How can I use this view to structure the React form? Any suggestion?

Comment: its a bit complicated, but its storing the data from the API call in the state in componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps, unfortunately I cannot tell you more since its not me who developed the react forms.